# Passing by reference to imported functions that attempt to update the arguments?

Tags: javascript, module

Please suppose module main.js imports a set of functions that are event handlers for event listeners registered by main.js; and, when the imported handler functions are invoked, objects in main.js (that were not exported to the other module) are passed as arguments in those functions and those functions attempt to alter property values in the passed objects.

When I test it, the objects (when subsequently used in main.js) reflect the changes made in the other module.

Is this okay to rely upon pass-by-reference for an object between modules; or must those objects be exported from main.js and imported by the other module?

Thank you.

Comment: that's how javascript objects work

Comment: I understand that within the same module; but, after reading about importing/exporting between modules, it seemed a bit unusual to be able to change a non-exported object by passing it as a funciton argument.

Comment: modules are relative newcomers to javascript - javascript still works like javascript

Comment: @Gary an object is not "owned" by a module or anything.

Comment: Perhaps I overthought it a bit because of remembering about having to do extra work to share objects between content scripts and page scripts in web extensions (which, of course, this is not an extension and does not apply here). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The answer is yes, since the objects are assigned/passed as arguments by reference you can expect the same behavior between modules. But there're some considerations.
2. There's an encapsulation principle that means modules should share as less data as possible. So share less data and communicate with functions (your interface/api/protocol to your data).
3. A case against functional programming for global state management (your data in modules): avoid using rewriting your object references. Having many objects is hard to manage you can override one reference but forget update the other. Use `const` with all objects and update the with `Object.assign`. That way you will be sure you have all your objects actual and don't have mess with object references.

So basically you should have a stable private not referenced (not shared) objects in your modules if you care about the encapsulation.